# Compare data between databases with difftype=data liquibase

Tags: sql, database, diff, liquibase

I try to integrate a versioning system for my databases. I use liquibase.

I work with the diff system because I modify the sql directly and I don't want to have to report the changes I made manually.

It works for schemas but not really for datas. I tried to use the `difftype=data` on `generatechangelog` but I don't know how to do to compare 2 databases datas.

Do you have any solution ?

Answer (score 4):

If you are comparing databses you want to use diffChangeLog rather than generateChangeLog. GenerateChangeLog outputs the full creation logic for a single database, it doesn't compare two databases.

GenerateChangeLog supports the diffType=data attribute which will output the contents of a database as csv or insert statements, but there is no support for comparing data in two databases.