# Can diffChangelog generete difference in DML?

Tags: oracle, liquibase

Like in post title. Is it possibile to generate diff changelog with changes on data ? I wanted to generate such a file without success - output file is empty. I use following command :

```
liquibase --driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver --classpath=c:\libs\ojdbc14-10.2.0.1.0.jar  --changeLogFile=c:\liquibase\DIFF_DML.xml --url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:9876:XE --username=user --password=pass --diffTypes="data"  diffChangeLog --referenceUrl=jdbc:oracle:thin:@centos:1521:XE --referenceUsername=user --referencePassword=pass
```

Parameter --diffTypes="data" is sucesfully generating DML in generateChangeLog command, but does it work also on diff ? If no, is there any solution to get difference between two databses by data inserted to them ?

Comment: There is no such option in the manual: http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/command_line.html so I guess the answer is: no, Liquibase can't do that

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19407999/332248) by @Nathan Voxland says: "...there is no support for comparing data in two databases."